# Sanity intl plugin / Allow GraphQL to query __i18n_lang by removing the underscores from field name

Tags: reactjs, graphql, sanity

GraphQL ignores fields that start with double underscore `__i18n_lang` and I cant query the language from Sanity. The Sanity Intl plugin has already a solution how to replace the name but the Docs are not very friendly for a Sanity beginner like me.

Please help me implement [this code](https://github.com/LiamMartens/sanity-plugin-intl-input/blob/develop/docs/graphql-intl-doc.md) on my Sanity studio.

OR

help me create a new field `lang` that automatically gets the value of `__i18n_lang` using sanity api.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to sort it?

Comment: Hi Fabio, at that time I was using GatsbyJS, and only GraphQL worked there. The only way was checking suffix of `_id` but still was a bit unreliable. Now I use NextJS and work directly with GROQ query instead and works perfect.